# Selenium grid parallel execution using a single source to read data from

Tags: java, selenium, grid

According to our framework we have a sheet where the test cases are defined for execution.Using Selenium grid, we need to read the sheet which contains the test cases and steps and all this tests should run in parallel.

**Example:**

Consider we have 100 tests which need to run, If i have 3 nodes each node should pick up different test cases to run.

if TC 001 is run by node1, node2 should not pick up the TC001 and it should pickup TC002.

Could you please help us where can we keep this method for reading the datasheet through which we can achieve this